# Android: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected

Tags: android, google-api

I am integrating Google Plus in my android app when I was trying to sign in to Google Plus my app just crashed. It says -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected
```

Below is the line number which stacktrace points towards,

```
if (Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient) != null)

@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        String personName = "Unknown";
        if (Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            personName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient); 
        }
}
```

I have done all steps for integration, added Google play services to my project and registered my app on Google API's site.

Comment: can u post complete code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Google play games services connection error ( java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474986/android-google-play-games-services-connection-error-java-lang-illegalstateexc)

Answer (score -1):

First check if it is connected, then do your stuff.

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
  // good
}else{
  //connect it
  mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
}
```

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41914564/5292302) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplica‌​te-answer-to-several-questions)

Answer (score -4):

Duplicate of : [Android: Google play games services connection error ( java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient must be connected.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474986/android-google-play-games-services-connection-error-java-lang-illegalstateexc)

Anyways, modify your code to:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        String personName = "Unknown";
        if (isSignedIn()) {
          if (Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            personName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient); 
          }
        }
}
```

Comment: hi, what does  isSingedIn() method contain?