# Google Play Games Services doesnt connect

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to use Google Play Games Services, but when calling `Games.Achievements.unlock` or `Games.Leaderboards.submitScore` I get errors `GoogleApiClient is not connected yet` and `GoogleApiClient must be connected` respectively.

The curious thing is that when using `Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent` works and the scoreboard is displayed. I tried using the methods in onCreate, onResume, and onStart, and it generates the same error.
When calling those methods by some button click, it works. But i cant request my user to click a button to unlock some achievement.

In gradle:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'`

Comment: Just a suggestion from your code since I am assuming you have one. Try to check first if the `GoogleApiClient` is connected before doing any action. A simple `if{ //connected }else{ //establish connection}` will do. Also, try to explore this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474986/android-google-play-games-services-connection-error-java-lang-illegalstateexc).

Comment: i did. Still just works in button clicks.